# Unable to deploy a Liferay portlet

Tags: java, gradle, liferay

In my Liferay (gradle) project in one module I added a new dependency in `build.gradle` file of a module like this:

```
compile group: "org.apache.commons", name: "commons-lang3", version: "3.4"
```

Then I ran the deploy script.
Deploy script does not return errors, however, Liferay is unable to deploy this module.
When I start the Liferay, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 60d05c84-6e0e-001d-100e-e4594733331c][f-b-b:97] FrameworkEvent ERROR 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: f-b-b [738]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.lang3; version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

When I try to load the page where the portlet is located, I get another error:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: /home/user/projects/project/workspace/bundles/osgi/state/org.eclipse.osgi/733/0/.cp/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:305)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.basicOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getZipFile(ZipBundleFile.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.checkedOpen(ZipBundleFile.java:65)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleFile.getEntry(ZipBundleFile.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:330)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:407)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at com.sun.beans.finder.ClassFinder.findClass(ClassFinder.java:103)
        at java.beans.Introspector.findCustomizerClass(Introspector.java:1301)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetBeanDescriptor(Introspector.java:1295)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:425)
        at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.JspTagModelBase.<init>(JspTagModelBase.java:53)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TagTransformModel.<init>(TagTransformModel.java:51)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$TldParserForTaglibBuilding.endElement(TaglibFactory.java:1736)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.parseXml(TaglibFactory.java:872)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.access$1400(TaglibFactory.java:94)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$Taglib.parseToTagsAndFunctions(TaglibFactory.java:1507)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory$Taglib.<init>(TaglibFactory.java:1490)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.loadTaglib(TaglibFactory.java:846)
        at freemarker.ext.jsp.TaglibFactory.get(TaglibFactory.java:256)
        at com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.internal.FreeMarkerManager$TaglibFactoryWrapper.get(FreeMarkerManager.java:650)
        at com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker.internal.FreeMarkerManager.addTaglibSupport(FreeMarkerManager.java:206)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doIncludeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:276)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.doDispatch(ThemeUtil.java:157)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeFTL(ThemeUtil.java:100)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:82)
        at com.liferay.taglib.theme.WrapPortletTag.doEndTag(WrapPortletTag.java:101)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:1863)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
      at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.includePage(IncludeTag.java:372)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.include(IncludeTag.java:349)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doInclude(IncludeTag.java:202)
        at com.liferay.taglib.util.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:86)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1827)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._render(PortletContainerImpl.java:707)
        at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:162)
        at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:133)
        at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:133)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:161)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:126)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:73)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:444)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:286)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:113)
        at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:125)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:70)
        at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:759)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutTypeControllerImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutTypeControllerImpl.java:168)
        at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutImpl.java:897)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:323)
        at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:159)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
        at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:170)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:583)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:337)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:153)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.uploadservletrequest.UploadServletRequestFilter.processFilter(UploadServletRequestFilter.java:93)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:336)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:125)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:337)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:364)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:261)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:265)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:142)
        at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
        at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
        at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/projects/project/workspace/bundles/osgi/state/org.eclipse.osgi/733/0/.cp/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar (No such file or folder)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:228)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:157)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:288)
        ... 222 more
```

So it looks like it can not find the right jar file. But, deploy is successful, no errors while building the project. If I put the invalid name in `build.gradle`, like `commons-lang300` I get the build error, what means that gradle is able to download the library `commons-lang3` just fine. Somewhy Liferay is not able to find it.

If I do not use the `org.apache.commons.lang` package in my source code, portlet is deployed without problems. If I try to use it, portlet does not want to deploy.

I remember adding libraries in other modules in `build.gradle` and I was able to use them.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deploy portlet with dependencies not included in liferay you can include them in the component jar this way in build.gradle change to

```
compileInclude group: "org.apache.commons", name: "commons-lang3", version: "3.4"
```

then in the bnd.bnd file ad this instruction

```
Import-Package: \
*;resolution:=optional
```

One other solution is to keep the gradle dependecy in compile

```
compile group: "org.apache.commons", name: "commons-lang3", version: "3.4"
```

and add to the bnd.bnd this instruction to decide manually which jar to include

```
-includeresource: @commons-lang3-3.4.jar

Import-Package: \
    *;resolution:=optional
```

Comment: This solution is confirmed to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Liferay Workspace, you could omit the commons-lang version and just use the one that Liferay brings.

When I'm looking at Liferay DXP 7.4 U34, I see that it brings along apache-commons-lang 3.11.0 (through gogo-shell `lb commons`) while the unzip error message tries to find 3.4 explicitly. You might want to try just omitting the version number to get what's coming with the portal. Or bring along your own 3.4 - technically, as OSGi is looking for `[3.4.0,4.0.0)` though, it should find 3.11.0

Also, you might want to try compiling against the same version that you're deploying to.

And last but not least: The folder osgi/state is one that you can also delete, and it'll be regenerated - you might want to try that as a quickfix as well.

More about dependency declaration can be taken from the [release announcement](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-4-ga34-and-liferay-commerce-4-0-ga34-release), in this case for Liferay Portal CE:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
}
```

Or for Liferay DXP:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.dxp.api"
}
```

The actually deployed version comes from your workspace's gradle.properties, for example:

```
liferay.workspace.product=dxp-7.4-u34
```

Edit: As you say in your comment: Deploying the required version to the OSGi runtime yourself is also another option. This introduces a second version of some already existing library though. While OSGi can handle it, it might lead to unexpected results down the line, when you try to interpret one of those classes for another version of itself - so I generally prefer not to go this route if at all possible.

Sometimes it's your only way out though. And in that case, you'll just need to make sure that your plugin brings all its dependencies.

You didn't mention the Liferay version you're running (and the commons-lang version that it is running) - if you're on an older version, you might ask for a newer version than the one that Liferay brings. And that naturally can't resolve.

Comment: I tried without specifying the version number, but it still looks for version 3.4. Even if I specify the version 3.5 in my gradle file, it still looks for 3.4 when loading this module. Even if i remove the whole ```compile``` line from gradle file, it still looks for 3.4..

I tried deleting the osgi state, but the same thing happens.

I managed to temporary make it work by manually copying the ```commons-lang3-3.4.jar``` into Liferay's deploy folder after the deploy. After that Liferay says ```STARTED f-b-b [1784]``` and portlet works as expected.

Comment: But I can not seam to get this to deploy automatically.

Comment: edited: If you declare a dependency that's not already there, then you'll need to bring it yourself - there's no way around it.